# Google Calendar (Google Apps): Can I share a calendar with the outside world (to see all events) but require a password?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, google-workspace

I want to share my Google Apps calendars with the outside world (users not in my Google Apps) but I want to require a password for access.  When I configure the calendar to allow outside access like so:

[image]

and then on the individual calendar basis like so:

[image]

I get big scary warnings that this makes the calendar available public via Google search etc.  I want to make the calendar available to the outside world but require a Google account so I can authenticate them if I want.

Comment: Google Calendar does not have this ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google had support for private calendar links until about a year ago.  They removed this feature, which I had been using for years to share calendar events for my cub scout pack, which needed to be easy to share but not public for the safety of the boys.  I switched over to Outlook.com this year, as it includes this feature.